# Accessability In Asp.Net: JAWS Screen Reader skips disabled fields ( Select, Radio, Check boxes )

Tags: asp.net, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader, wcag

I am attempting to create a screen that both a manager and a employee can view and answer questions.

Some questions can be answered by only the manager and some by only the employee.  both the manager and the employee can see each others answers.

I have a number of controls that I need to have displayed to the user as read-only (Dropdown selects, Radio buttons, check boxes)

These control types do not have a read-only option.

I need a way that I can set these as read only,

if I set them to disabled, then that works nicely for normal users BUT completely fails when users are using accessibility software (JAWS) as they are then skipped.

**I would prefer to not have to write JavaScript to do this.**

Is there a way to make disabled controls show up in the tab order for JAWS? 
Or flag them in some way with Arias?

Answer (score 1):

> if I set them to disabled, then that works nicely for normal users BUT completely fails when users are using accessibility software (JAWS) as they are then skipped.

They are not in the focus order, but they can be accessed by screen reader users via cursor keys, so I would suggest this is a non-issue.